# How pass entirety of hiera data into a script from puppet?

Tags: puppet, hiera

I would like to transition from using puppet to plain old scripts. During this transition I would like for scripts to access the information in hiera. Is there a way for puppet to pass the all key value pairs to a script as an argument through an `exec`? If I could get puppet to pass a json blob of hiera into a script that would be perfect.

Through experimentation in my hiera file contains

```
{
    "a" : ["a, b"],
    "b" : "b",
    "c" : {
        "a" : {
            "b" : "c"
        }
    }
}
```

1. hiera("a"): "ab"
2. hiera("b"): "b"
3. hiera("c"): ""
4. hiera(""): ""

Ideally I'd like to pass the entire json string from all hiera data sources into my scripts from puppet's `exec`? Can anyone confirm if this is possible, or if there is some work around?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you are trying to do? It is somewhat unclear.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way for puppet to pass the all key value pairs to a script as an argument through an `exec`?

Not in general, no, because Hiera resolutions can be context-sensitive.  There is no guarantee that "all key value pairs" is well-defined on a whole-node basis.  Therefore, before even talking about how the data can be exchanged, you need to deal with the problem of what the data *are*.

Even if you suppose that none of the Hiera facilities are in use that contextualize data more narrowly than on a node-by-node basis, and that you need be concerned only with priority lookups (not array- or hash-merge lookups), Hiera has no built-in facility for compiling a composite of all data pertaining to a node.  If you're dealing only with the standard YAML or JSON back-end, however, you could probably create and use your own hacked version that extracts the desired data, maybe as the value of some special key.

Even then, however, passing the data themselves as a command-line argument is highly questionable.  You would need, first, to serialize the data into a form that will be interpreted as a single shell word.  That surely can be automated, but next you risk running afoul of argument-length limits.  A conforming POSIX system can impose a maximum argument length as small as 4096 bytes (though many have much larger limits) and that could easily be too little.  And if you're trying to do this with Windows then know that its limits are even smaller.

As an alternative to passing the data as a command-line argument, you could consider writing them to a file that your script(s) will read.  Even that seems a bit silly, however.  Hiera has a CLI -- why not just distribute the Hiera data and hierarchy configuration, and have your scripts use Hiera to query the needed data from it?

Answer (score 0):

In general, this is no supposed to work.

You might be able to write a custom Hiera backend that recognizes a special lookup key and return a fully merged hash of all data from the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I have got the question correctly, but I assume you are talking about some templating? You can use templates and put value in the placeholders.

Check out this link, if this helps.

http://codingbee.net/tutorials/puppet/puppet-generate-files-templates-using-hiera-data/

Comment: I ended up using templates, but still cannot pass in entirety of hiera configuration. I would have to specify keys I need.

Comment: Yeah, I guess, that is the way to do it.